# Hg equivalent of "git log master..HEAD" when using bookmarks as lightweight branches?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, branch

Git users seeking to achieve a workflow involving lightweight branches in Mercurial are often [pointed](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/git-branches-on-mercurial) to [Mercurial bookmarks](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/bookmarks/). In a nutshell, the recommendation is to maintain multiple heads that would correspond to the git branches, and name them with bookmarks.

A common desire in such a workflow is to see a list of all commits made in the current branch since the point it was branched from the parent branch (commonly `master` or another long-lived branch). In git, this can be accomplished with:

```
git log <master>..HEAD
```

where `<master>` is the name of the parent branch.

I am wondering, what would be the equivalent of this command in Mercurial with bookmarks?

I am looking for a command with the following properties:

- It has the same semantics as the git command above in terms of which revisions it lists and in what order (obviously).
- Like the git command, it does not involve typing the name of the current "branch" (bookmark).
- It does not require the existence of a bookmark at the point where the current "branch" diverged from the parent "branch". It may require the existence of a bookmark pointing to the head of the parent "branch" - we can call this bookmark `master`.
- It is short. I'd really rather not type a long revset expression that has to be enclosed in quotes every time I want to do this. (That said, I've yet to figure out *any* revset expression that gives me what I want, so even a long one would be progress.)

Comment: Can you show (some) Git's DAG and mark relevant for `git log <master>..HEAD` part of history on it? Let's assume I have zero-knowledge about Git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git log man-page (with link to Git revisions man-page) defines range specifications like that as follows:

```
<rev1>..<rev2>

   Include commits that are reachable from <rev2> but exclude those that are reachable from <rev1>.
```

It also say about order:

```
By default, the commits are shown in reverse chronological order.
```

Given this specification, the Mercurial revset

```
reverse(ancestors(.)-ancestors(<bookmark>))
```

should be sufficient.

On a closer look, this revset actually follows the specification down to the letter. It shows in reverse order the commits reachable from the current working copy's parent excluding those reachable from the given bookmark ("master" in your case). I consider Git's syntax a shorthand for this specification. You can do the same (creating a shortcut) in Mercurial using the so-called revset aliases.

Putting the following lines into your .hgrc:

```
[revsetalias] 
range($1)=reverse(ancestors(.)-ancestors($1))
```

will enable you to use this:

```
hg log -r range(<bookmark>)
```

If you want to make it more flexible, you can define it like this in the .hgrc:

```
[revsetalias] 
range($1,$2)=reverse(ancestors($2)-ancestors($1))
```

and use the following to get the HEAD example:

```
hg log -r range(<bookmark>, .)
```

If the word "range" is too much to type for you, you can use some special characters, too:

```
[revsetalias] 
_($1)=reverse(ancestors(.)-ancestors($1))
```

The resulting shorthand

```
hg log -r_(<bookmark>)
```

is then even shorter than

```
git log <bookmark>..HEAD
```

But of course this is just nitpicking, anyway.

Comment: If you use revsets, revset's *infix operators* will be **better**, than  *predicates*: i. e. `"x::y"` or `"x:y"` (depending from conditions: DAG or revisions numbers range)

Comment: But those do not result in what the OP wanted. x::y shows the DAG range, x:y shows the chronological range. Even though x..y is a valid shortcut for x::y in Mercurial, it does not do what Git's x..y does, just as quoted in my answer from Git's man-pages.

Comment: It **DOES** the same set. sort-order is another, next question

Comment: Mercurial's x..y does not do the same thing as Git's x..y . If you have 2 topological branches A and B that diverge at some common ancestor point C, Mercurial's x..y will display nothing for A..B, while Git's A..B will show you commits B-C', with C' being the immediate child of C on B's side.

Comment: @LazyBadger: In the discussed case, `master` is a bookmark to the **head** of the parent "branch", which may not be an ancestor of the current head.

Comment: In tis case master can't be "bookmark to the head of branch", because it's Mercurial - it can be **any amount** of heads in any named branch, bookmarked changeset **always inherit** branch (and all changeset **always have** associated named branch), in which it appeared first time. I.e - *your "master"* is useless and overhead data. My "master" - point of born for bookmark

Comment: @LazyBadger: I put "branch" in quotes because I was referring not to a named branch but to the series of commits starting with the one where my line of work diverged from the main line, and ending at my current commit - the thing that would be a branch in git. Everything is all on the same named branch in my case. The reason I can't use your approach is because I don't have a way of naming X other than by revision ID.

Comment: @Face: Thanks, your approach works. One minor annoyance, though, is that I find I have to put the revset expression (including the shortened one) into quotes, otherwise my shell gives me: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`. This is unfortunate because having to type quotes (and parentheses, for that matter), makes it quite a bit more annoying to type than the git command.

Comment: @HighCommander4 - you **can** name X with *any* semantic name. Just mark starting revision by two bookmarks and don't touch one

Comment: @HighCommander4: I see. I tested it on Windows, where this is no issue.

Comment: @LazyBadger: You see, my answer gives him the same results as Git's command does. The DAG range function only give the same results in certain DAG situations, but not in all. Thus it is not the same. Using vulgar language doesn't make this simple fact go away.

Comment: @LazyBadger: Then I would need to have **two** bookmarks for each branch: one at the beginning and one at the end. Moreover, the name of the one at the beginning would have to be something related to the branch (since there is one for each branch), so it fails my requirement that "it does not involve typing the name of the current 'branch' (bookmark)". Nevertheless, it's good to be aware of this alternative approach.

Comment: @HighCommander4: LazyBadger's approach would fail your requirement of not having to mark the divergence point, because Mercurial's x..y simply don't work if x is not an ancestor of y. The reason for this is right there in "hg help revsets". It states that x::y (or x..y) is `A DAG range, meaning all changesets that are descendants of x and ancestors of y, including x and y themselves. If the first endpoint is left out, this is equivalent to "ancestors(y)", if the second is left out it is equivalent to "descendants(x)".` This is clearly not the same as Git's specification mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Face: Yeah, I'm aware. LazyBadger just seemed to suggest that having to mark the divergence point isn't a big deal, and I explained why it is.

Comment: @HighCommander4: if you come from hg's native branch mechanism - that really is nothing more than node coloring with benefits - it is easy to misunderstand the need for an equivalent of Git's revision range specifier. With named branches, displaying the set of commits belonging to a branch is very easy, as the divergence point simply is the first commit having the appropriate "color". Git OTOH can't distinguish common changesets of two topological branches, because it only uses pointers to the heads of both lines. Thus there is the need to use set-functions with given ordering to list them.

Comment: @HighCommander4 - using (internal) naming convention **and** slightly changed workflow **and** one addinional alias for hg command you can avoid typing *any* bookmark name

Comment: @HighCommander4 - BTW, how you work with bookmarked anon-branch. Is it's history linear (i.e doesn't contain additional branchpoints and mergesets) or is it complex DAG?

Comment: @Face: I'll have to re-read the various things I've read that recommend bookmarks over named branches to get a better idea of the differences, but I'd imagine there must be a reason for this advice...

Comment: @LazyBadger: I keep each of my bookmarked anon-branches' history linear.